# Concatenating select part of split string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

If I have a string:

```
str = "This is my string"
```

And I split it:

```
str.split (" ")
```

to obtain:

```
["This","is","my","string"]
```

I wonder how to concatenate it in order to obtain:

```
["This","is","my string"]
```

This isn't my exact problem. I'm parsing log files and need to figure out how to concatenate a certain part of each line after splitting it.

Comment: and how should this line `"This is my string and there is some other string"` be splitted?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Based on what? The index?

Comment: Based on the index, yes.

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
>>> "This is my string".split(" ", 2)
['This', 'is', 'my string']
>>>
```

Comment: "This isn't my exact problem"

Comment: Then please elaborate on your exact problem. So that we can provide solution for it.

Comment: I'm not the OP, just explaining why this isn't really a suitable answer to such a broad and unclear question.

Comment: This solves it actually, since I know the index till where the string should be split. Thank you!